# Question about a step in the proof of: If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, then it is continuous.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$,
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0).$$

So, $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)-f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} f'(x_0)(x-x_0)=0$.

Thus, $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$.

Thus, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Since $x_0$ was arbitrary, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

---

My question is: about the step going from $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0)$ to $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)-f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$.

How are we allowed to do this?

Are we multiplying through by $x-x_0$? Is this allowed? Is it creating a new limit on the right side?

Comment: No, we're multiplying through by $\lim_{x\to x_0}x-x_0$

Comment: @saulspatz no, theres no multiplying through

Comment: @CalvinKhor Why do you say that?  The limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits.

Comment: @saulspatz Because you aren't using quotient rule. If you multiplied through by $\lim_{x\to x_0} x-x_0 = 0$ you should always get $0=0$. If there is any multiplying to be done, it has to be before you take limits.

Comment: @CalvinKhor. Actually, you can break up the limit of a quotient by separating the limit into a quotient of limits using the Algebraic Limit Theorem. And you may certainly multiply through by $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}(x-x_0)$.

Comment: @JB071098. I find it incredible that you insist on the quotient rule for limits when the denominator vanishes. Have you actually tried to write down what you are saying, do you realise that you are suggesting we divide by zero? And of course, you *may* multiply your equation by 0. But what's the point?

Comment: @CalvinKhor There is no need for hostility or sarcasm here. I assure you that my comment on quotients of limits was by no means a personal attack on your intellect. Thanks.

Comment: @JB071098 Sorry, I didn't mean for it to be hostile. I'm confused that multiple people are suggesting this all at once? Perhaps I am indeed wrong about something, in which case I hope one of you tells me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its $\lim \frac{a}{b} = c$, so that $\lim a = \lim (\frac ab b) = \lim \frac{a}{b} \lim b = c\lim b.$ We used two things, namely we are allowed to divide by $b$ when computing the limit $b\to 0$, and that limits have a product rule.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align*}\lim f(x)-f(x_0)&=\lim\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}(x-x_0)\\&=\lim\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\lim (x-x_0)\\&=f'(x_0)\cdot0\\&=0\end{align*}$$

Comment: This is the succint and unconfusing way! +1

Comment: Yes, I know this way too. I am not asking about another proof though. My question is: about the step going from $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0)$ to $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)-f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$.

How are we allowed to do this?

Comment: @AlJebr The only reason this implication holds is **because** of the correct proof.

Comment: @AlJebr: the proof in your question omits certain steps which are given explicitly in this answer. Unless you are experienced in the art of calculus, it is best not to omit steps.

Answer (score 0):

Note that differentiability is really much stronger than continuity:
you require the ratio to effectively have a limit.

But it suffice for the ratio to be bounded (which happen to be the case since differentiability means $f'(x_0)$ exists and is finite).

Indeed $\left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\right|\le M\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|\le M|x-x_0|\to 0$ and $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this:

Since
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0),$$

then $$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0)+\alpha,$$where $\alpha$ stands for an infinitesimal under the process $x \to x_0$.

Thus, $$f(x)-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\alpha(x-x_0).$$

Take the limits of both sides as $x \to x_0.$ We obtain $$\lim_{x \to x_0}[f(x)-f(x_0)]=f'(x_0) \cdot 0+0 \cdot 0=0,$$ which is desired.